# Would this be the correct usage of an expression tree?

Tags: c#, expression-trees

I've these two similar methods and I feel they can be replaced with an expression tree passing in the greater than or less than signs

```
public List<IAccount> IsGreater(DateTime someDate)
{    
    return AccountList.Where(a => 
           a.AccountDate >= someDate && a.SomeBoolMethod() && a.SomeOtherBoolMethod()) 
}

public List<IAccount> IsLess(DateTime someDate)
{    
    return AccountList.Where(a => 
           a.AccountDate < someDate && a.SomeBoolMethod() && a.SomeOtherBoolMethod())   
}
```

From what I've read about expression trees I feel something like this could be in order

```
 Expression<Func<DateTime, ExpressionType, DateTime, bool, bool, bool, List<IAccount>>> 
      expression = (a, b, c, d, e, f) =>
      {
          // not sure how to do this here
      }
```

Am I in the right neighborhood?

Comment: This seems to more like a [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) type question.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError This seems to be example code which is off-topic on Code Review.

Comment: Sounds like a great idea, I didn't know that existed. Is there a way I can just move it ?

Comment: Are those bool methods to be passed in or static within the method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why build an entire expression tree? As the question is currently stated, you can just pass in the comparison.

```
public List<IAccount> FilterAccounts( Predicate<IAccount> condition )
{    
    return AccountList.Where(a => condition(a) && a.SomeBoolMethod() && a.SomeOtherBoolMethod() )
}

public List<IAccount> IsGreater(DateTime someDate)
{    
    return FilterAccounts( a => a.AccountDate >= someDate );
}

public List<IAccount> IsLess(DateTime someDate)
{    
    return FilterAccounts( a => a.AccountDate < someDate );
}
```

Comment: Looks great, I'd suggest also showing an example of using your `FilterAccounts()` method for the OP.

Comment: You mean, more of an example than using it in `IsGreater` and `IsLess` as I have already done? If you have something specific in mind, feel free to add it!

Comment: Haha no worries, know what that feels like! :)

Comment: Thanks again for answering this. After the suggestion to move it to Code Review, I did that and they shot that down saying it wasn't a valid question. They also suggested I post it in stack over flow.